# RavenDB - HTTP request to return data in format other than CSV or JSON

Tags: json, csv, format, ravendb, ravendb-http

I'm running RavenDB v3.0. According to the [RavenDB documentation](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/how-to/integrate-with-excel), you are able to access an HTTP link to export a list of documents in CSV format. I've followed the instructions and can generate the export by connecting to an address similar to their example:

http://my-server/databases/db-name/streams/query/DocumentsForExtract?resultsTransformer=TransformForExtract&format=excel

The above URL will return the extract in CSV format. If I remove the format parameter from the request, or alter it to anything else, it returns it in JSON. I want to know if there are any other formats available? I'd like to get it in XML if possible, but I can't seem to find any documentation about this which is why I'm asking here on SO.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that endpoint supports only CSV and JSON